# Перепринятие чужого ответа на свой

Tags: обсуждение

Данная ситуация появляется редко, но обсуждению её есть место.

Ситуация следующая:

был задан [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/646663/205238) → был получен [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/646682/205238) (и принят) → автор модифицировал (несущественно) код, предложенный в принятом ответе → создал ответ c модифицированным кодом → принял [свой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648065/205238).

Что делать автору ответа, потерявшего "заветную галочку"?

Примеры вопросов с данной ситуацией:

1. [Как сохранять значение после выхода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/646663/205238)
2. [как сделать чтобы кнопки шли в ряд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/646969/205238)

Comment: _Что делать автору ответа, потерявшего "заветную галочку"?_ - ничего

Comment: @Grundy, при том, что один и тот же спрашивающий сделал так несколько раз? Не уверен, что ничего.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это его галочка :-) куда хотит, туда и ставит. Тем более ему от нее ни холодно ни жарко.

Comment: не ради *репы* же Мы отвечаем на вопросы в конце то концов :)

Comment: @Bald у каждого своя мотивация

Comment: *репу* за хороший ответ Вы *собрали*, галочкой ТС распоряжается так как ему заблагорассудиться с этим следует смириться

Comment: @Bald с этим я не спорю, но чувство справедливости (нет, не неутолённое ЧСВ) не даёт мне покоя. Думаю, если бы проблема была более распространена - появился бы механизм её решения..

Comment: @zTrap , такой механизм есть — можно задавать свои вопросы и расставлять там галочки самому.

Comment: если хочется <strike>потешить ЧСВ</strike> *справедливости* то можно смело *влепить* минус *дубликату*/обходить сторой данного участника

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous, это совершенно не связанные вещи. Свой вопрос и ответ это не механизм решения данной проблемы.

Comment: @Bald это то же самое что минусовать свой ответ потому что <strike>там мой код</strike> он не сильно отличается от ответа.

Comment: @zTrap , есть прямая связь: правильную постановку ответа на свой вопрос признать может только сам автор вопроса. Для того, чтобы качественные ответы не затмил авторский произвол, существует параллельный механизм оценки (оценка сообществом) — «карма».